# Serverless / AWS API Gateway CORS Unable to Access Headers

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, axios, serverless-framework

My function's config:

```
register:
  handler: handlers.register
  events:
    - http:
        integration: lambda-proxy
        path: register
        method: post
        cors: true
```

`OPTIONS` is returning these headers to the browser:

```
access-control-allow-credentials:false
access-control-allow-headers:Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,X-Amz-User-Agent
access-control-allow-methods:OPTIONS,POST
access-control-allow-origin:*
```

My `POST` method is returning these headers to the browser:

```
access-control-allow-credentials:true
access-control-allow-headers:Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token
access-control-allow-methods:*
access-control-allow-origin:*
...
x-amzn-remapped-authorization:Bearer {MY_TOKEN}
```

I send back a response from my handler with an `Authorization` header containing `Bearer {MY_TOKEN}`. I'm still, however, unable to access `x-amzn-remapped-authorization` from my JS client using axios. All I get back in JS is `content-type`.

Answer (score 2):

**Access-Control-Allow-Headers** is returned in a preflight response (from `OPTIONS`) by the server (in this case, API Gateway) for specifying which headers the client can use when making a request.

**Access-Control-Expose-Headers** is specified in your handler's response indicating which headers you want the browser to *expose* to the client.

I added `'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'X-Amzn-Remapped-Authorization'` to my handler's response and everything is now working as expected.